# An error occured using Eigen::Map after pass by const reference

Tags: c++, constants, pass-by-reference, eigen

The code giving me an error is like below. And when I remove the "const" from the parameter type, it worked.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include</usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core>
using namespace std;

void func(const vector<double>& x)
{
  Eigen::VectorXd X=Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd>(&x[0], x.size());
}

int main(){
  vector<double> x(100);
  func(x);
}
```

The error is like below. I can't understand it. Could anybody explain it to me? And is there a good way to do the same thing with "const" keyword?

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘const value_type* {aka const double*}’ to ‘Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1>, 0, Eigen::Stride<0, 0> >::PointerArgType {aka double*}’ [-fpermissive]
   Eigen::VectorXd X=Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd>(&x[0], x.size());
```

Comment: the error message is clear, `&x[0]` is a `const double*` and your eigen function expect a `double *`, you can't convert from `const double*` to `double*`

Comment: OK, here's the explanation. The `vector` argument `x` for `func` is passed as const reference: `const vector<double>& x`, meaning that it can not be modified. When you map the internal data of `x` using `Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd>` without indicating `const` in the template parameter, you are asking for a **non-const** conversion from a const reference. Such a conversion is not permitted by C++. So per ggael's suggestion, use either `Eigen::Map<const Eigen::VectorXd>` or `Eigen::VectorXd::Map`.

Comment: @Tyker Well you can, using `const_cast<double*>(&x[0])`, but that is usually not the right solution.

Comment: @chtz as you said it isn't a good solution. so don't want to advise it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either use the static method `VectorXd::Map` to automatically infer constness:

```
Eigen::VectorXd X = Eigen::VectorXd::Map(x.data(), x.size());
```

or make it const explicitly:

```
Eigen::VectorXd X = Eigen::Map<const Eigen::VectorXd>(x.data(), x.size());
```

And instead of doing a deep copy within a `VectorXd` you might prefer to name the `Map` object to directly use it:

```
Eigen::Map<const Eigen::VectorXd> X(x.data(), x.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
void func(vector<double>& x)
{
  Eigen::VectorXd X=Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd>(x.data(), x.size());
}
```